# How to use Collectors.grouping in Java 8 Stream API to create a Map

Tags: java, java-stream

I am looking for the first time to the Stream API of Java 8. And I have tried to create a filter to remove elements from a Map.

This is my Map:

```
Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
```

I want to remove entries with value <= than 0. So I want to apply a filter and get back a new map(Map<String, Integer>).

This is what I have been trying:

```
m.entrySet().stream().filter( p -> p.getValue() > 0).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.getKey()));
```

I get a HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap$Node>>. So, not what I was looking for.

I also tried:

```
m.entrySet().stream().filter( p -> p.getValue() > 0).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map::Entry::getKey, Map::Entry::getValue));
```

And this causes:

```
// Error:(50, 132) java: method reference not expected here
```

Basically I don't know how to build the values of my new Map.

This is the [javadoc of Collectors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html), they wrote a few examples of groupingBy, but I have not been able to get it working.

So, how should I write the **collect** to get my Map built as I want?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to group the stream items again, they are already "mapped" - you just need to collect them:

```
m.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getValue() > 0)
    .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

imports:

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;
```